# PayPal $0 Dollar Transaction?

Tags: paypal, transactions

I have a client who wants a paypal shopping cart. All of the services have "Buy Now" buttons, all with different prices.

However, there is one service, which is a FREE 0 dollar service. The client wants the "Buy Now" button to remain there, to be consistent with the rest of the site.

Does anyone know how I can do a $0 dollar transaction with paypal? I can't find any insight on this being possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the `zero` and `0` tags are redundant.

Answer (score 15):

Leave the 'buy now' there, but just don't process that transaction through PayPal in your code. Do things behind the scenes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an item to a paypal cart with a zero price.  Same code as any other buy now button with $0 in the price field.

You don't have to do anything behind the scenes to make it work.

I just set one of my products to zero and tested it works!  You can just make the button and have it add a zero cost item to the cart.

It then adds to the cart!

What doesnt' happen is that paypal won't let you pay for the cart with zero total value.  So if it's the only item in the cart, after the buyer views the cart and hits "checkout" and then tries to sign onto their account.... at that point paypal puts up a message that says "please enter an amount that's more than zero."